# How to index only words with a minimum length using Apache Lucene 5.3.1?

Tags: apache, lucene, nlp, cpu-word, minimum

may someone give me a hint on how to index only words with a minimum length using Apache Lucene 5.3.1?

I've searched through the API but didn't find anything which suits my needs except [this](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/api/contrib-queries/org/apache/lucene/search/similar/MoreLikeThis.html), but I couldn't figure out how to use that.

Thanks!

Edit:
I guess that's important info, so here's a copy of my explanation of what I want to achieve from my reply below:

"I don't intend to use queries. I want to create a source code summarization tool for which I created a doc-term matrix using Lucene. Now it also shows single- or double-character words. I want to exclude them so they don't show up in the results as they have little value for a summary. I know I could filter them when outputting the results, but that's not a clean solution imo. An even worse would be to add all combinations of single- or double-character words to the stoplist. I am hoping there is a more elegant way then one of those."

Comment: Can you provide an example what you want to achieve? E.g. input data, query and result of this query.

Comment: I don't intend to use queries. I want to create a source code summarization tool for which I created a doc-term matrix using Lucene. Now it also shows single- or double-character words. I want to exclude them so they don't show up in the results as they have little value for a summary. I know I could filter them when outputting the results, but that's not a clean solution imo. An even worse would be to add all combinations of single- or double-character words to the stoplist. I am hoping there is a more elegant way then one of those.

Comment: There's an example of exactly what you're looking for in the [Javadocs](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a custom Analyzer with LengthTokeFilter. E.g.

```
Analyzer ana = CustomAnalyzer.builder()
                .withTokenizer("standard")
                .addTokenFilter("standard")
                .addTokenFilter("lowercase")     
                .addTokenFilter("length", "min", "4", "max", "50")
                .addTokenFilter("stop", "ignoreCase", "false", "words", "stopwords.txt", "format", "wordset")
                .build();
```

But it is better to use a stopword (words what occur in almost all documents, like articles for English language) list.  This gives a more accurate result.

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm!

Do you know if it is possible to use an absolute/relative path for the stopwords? 
Before, I created a StandardAnalyzer(CharArraySet) for the stopwords and could specify and file I wanted. Now the same doesn't work, but only for stopword-files which are in the same dir.

Comment: You should create builder by providing a path to resource directory e.g.  `CustomAnalyzer.builder(Paths.get("your_resources_dir"))`